# Handling Large Xml files in kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, alpakka

I am using Alpakka kafka with scala application. My Kafka is running inside docker and I am trying to publish message on Kafka producer using my code. My code is as follows

```
 def sendMsg(xmlFile: String): Future[Done] = {
    futureToFutureTry {
      val producer = SendProducer(producerSettings)
      producer.send(new ProducerRecord("topic_name", "Key", xmlFile)).map(result => {
        producer.close()
      })
    } flatMap {
      case Success(v) => v
      case Failure(e) =>
        Future.failed(e)
    }
  }
```

Code is fine but when I send large xml file it gives me `an error that org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 22093081 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.`

I can see some solutions on stackoverflow itself but none of them explains where do I need to make changes. How I can increase the maximum request size. I am new to kafka. When application starts I can see it is printing default max.request.size but don't know how it is printing that and how and where and what I need to do to resolve it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan to produce messages to Kafka larger than the default size of 1048588 bytes you need to change the settings at three different locations:

1. Topic Configuration
2. Producer Configuration
3. Consumer Configuration

#### Topic configuration

When creating the topic you need to ensure that you set `max.message.bytes` to a larger value. Setting this configuration when creating the Kafka topic could be done using the `kafka-topics` script:

```sh
bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic topic-name --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config max.message.bytes=50000000
```

Description of the this configuration is given [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.message.bytes):

> The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka (after compression if compression is enabled). If this is increased and there are consumers older than 0.10.2, the consumers' fetch size must also be increased so that the they can fetch record batches this large. In the latest message format version, records are always grouped into batches for efficiency. In previous message format versions, uncompressed records are not grouped into batches and this limit only applies to a single record in that case.

#### Producer Configuration

In your variable `producerSettings` you need to increase the value for `max.request.size`, for example:

```scala
val producerSettingsNew = producerSettings + ("max.request.size" -> "50000000")
```

The description of this setting is given [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.request.size):

> The maximum size of a request in bytes. This setting will limit the number of record batches the producer will send in a single request to avoid sending huge requests. This is also effectively a cap on the maximum uncompressed record batch size. Note that the server has its own cap on the record batch size (after compression if compression is enabled) which may be different from this.

#### Consumer Configuration

Also your consumer needs to be configured in the settings by increasing `max.partition.fetch.bytes`.

The description is given [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.partition.fetch.bytes):

> The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return. Records are fetched in batches by the consumer. If the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config). See fetch.max.bytes for limiting the consumer request size.